# How to read a linux background process stream through java?

Tags: java, linux, streaming

On my linux machine I have one process running in background.I have the process id of this process.I want to read the stream output of this process through java.
Command:

`nohup sar -A 1 >/dev/null 2>&1 &`

I am redirecting the output to /dev/null i.e. nohup.out will not be created.

Comment: You are explicitly redirecting every output to /dev/null. That means there is no output that you could read.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `nohup` and have an output stream.

From `nohup --help` :

> If standard output is a terminal, append output to 'nohup.out' if possible,
>   '$HOME/nohup.out' otherwise.

So either you drop the use of `nohup` and you can use the `Process`'s outputStream, or you have to read from a file.

Obviously in both cases you also have to stop redirecting the output of your command to `/dev/null`, but you can either redirect it to a file of your choice or let `nohup` use its default output file.

Comment: The command which I m executing on Linux machine generates the system performance reports like CPU , Memory, I/O.Any no of threads will read the output of this command. And as this command needs to be continuously running as a background process I cannot redirect the output to any file because it will increase the disk space.

Neither I can drop nohup as this command is getting executed through Java call.Droping nohup means it will become foreground process and Java will expect the command execution to be finished which will never be the case.

Comment: @Abhishek After checking `sar`'s documentation, it looks like you should leave the `sar` process alone and execute `sadc` to punctually retrieve system informations

Comment: I totally agree with you but the default sar utility provides the stats with the 10seconds time span where as I need the system statistics of every second which can be retrieved by command sar -A 1